# how to find a column letter from it's name or from a text in it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating a sheets with type and month, named datasheet,what I'd like to do is a look up part:

[image]

I'd like to create a formula that gives me the type 3 of a chosen month, so if I give January it
returns the type 3 of January

- So I created a list from my month

[image]

- and then I tried to create a formula on another sheet that used the reference of a cell to return me it's value

`=INDIRECT("datasheet!"&CHR(COLUMN(datasheet!B1)+64)&4)`

my question is how can I look for the column of a given column name or look for the first column in a row containing a specific text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH/MATCH

```
=INDEX(datasheet!A:M,MATCH(A1,datasheet!A:A,0),MATCH(B1,datasheet!1:1,0))
```

Comment: it looks efficient but can you explain more what are the 3 main given argument, I know A1 and B1 are the given argument for the lookup from the list but what are 'datasheets!A:M' , 'datasheet!A:A' and 'datasheet!1:1' (in simple words like 'your type range'/'your month range') ?

Comment: I am assuming your data is in columns `A:M` on the `datasheet`  It will look for `Type 3` in column A and  the month in row 1 and return the value at that intersection.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want it to give you the type3 value, and not use the row description to search, you could use an HLOOKUP for this.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hlookup-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f

```
=HLOOKUP(B1,datasheet!A1:M4,4)
```